# Masonry grid sizer issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been at this the whole day and I'm slowly losing will to live at this point because of this..
I was trying to create a system where recent posts fit all onto 1 page. Behold! I succeeded. Well, sort of.
I have ran into an issue using masonry, while trying to create that. When using '.grid-sizer', having it set in CSS and applied in HTML, it doesn't work at all.

For example:

```
    .grid-sizer {
Width: 49.62%;
    }
```

and HTML:

```
    <div id="msonryContainer"  class="js-masonry" data-masonry-options='{ "columnWidth":      ".grid-sizer", "itemSelector": ".post" }'>
    <div class="grid-sizer"></div>
    <div id="content">
```

Now for the love of God, that bloody thing doesn't work, every other option works, but the sizing of the grid doesn't. Unless I set div values to pixels, as opposed to percentage, since I am trying to make responsive layout, it doesn't work.

At this point all hope is pretty much lost, so I had to resort to posting here.

Just in case you wanna know how the mess looks:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rDce1.jpg